# Binding a Java Integer to JavaScriptEngine doesn't work

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

To see how binding Java objects to symbols in a dynamic language works, I wrote the following [spike test](http://jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/spike_solutions.html), binding a `java.lang.Integer` to the symbol `i` to be changed in JavaScript:

```
  @Test 
  public void bindToLocalVariable() throws ScriptException {

    javax.script.ScriptEngineManager sem 
       = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager();
    javax.script.ScriptEngine engine 
       = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");    

    Integer i = new Integer(17);

    engine.put( "i", i );        
    engine.eval( "i++;" );  // Now execute JavaScript

    assertEquals( 18, i.intValue() );        

    }
```

Unfortunately, I get a failure.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<18> but was:<17>
```

JavaScript knows the symbol `i` (otherwise it would have thrown a `ScriptException` which is not the case), but the increment operation `i++` is not performed on the original `Integer` object.

Any explanations?

Comment: Use `engine.get("i")` to get the value of `i` in the engine *after* you evaluated `"i++;"`. Remember that you have **two** things called `i` now: The local `Integer` variable in your `Java` application and the variable in your JavaScript engine.

Comment: Joachim, I don't have two things, but I have two names for one thing. One reference from Java, one from JavaScript.

Comment: @rplantiko: **no**, that's wrong. And you are even observing that it's not the case. There is **no way** that the JavaScript engine could change the value of `i` (and it can't change the value stored in the `Integer` object either, because `Integer` is immutable).

Comment: Jochim. As for immutability of Integer, I would expect autoboxing behind the scenes, as in the **Java** statement `i++;` which changes the value of i as well.

Comment: Joachim: But thank you for the main point of your comment. I didn't know that JS is not working on the original, but on a copy.

Comment: @rplantiko: the difference is that in `i++` the `i` is the *variable* itself, so you **do** have access to it (i.e. it's equivalent to assigning a new value to it). But `engine` (or the its methods) **can't** access (the local Java variable) `i`. Imagine this: what if you had used `engine.put("j", i); engine.eval("j++;");`? Would you expect `i` to be modified now?

Comment: @rplantiko: it's working on the **Object** referred to by `i`, not on a copy of it. But that's not the same thing as working on `i` itself. `i` is just a variable holding a reference, it's **not** an Object. This distinction is not often stated explicitly, but it's very important in this case.

Comment: Joachim: "what if you had used `engine.put("j", i); engine.eval("j++;");`"? I would expect the following: `j` would be the JS symbol pointing to the same object as the Java symbol `i` points to. This was my expectation, but it is wrong, as my test shows. It behaves differently: the content of `i` is not changed. Hence, `j` points only to a **copy** of the object `i` points to.

Comment: @rplantiko: I'm sorry to nag, but your conclusion is *still wrong*. `j` points to **the same object** as `i` (at least initially). Since that object can't be changed itself, changes to `j` must result in `j` pointing to a different object. My suggestion: try to reproduce the situations **without** introducing a script engine. Simply produce your own method `frobnicate(Integer)` that somehow manipulates its argument and see how that behaves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JavaSrciptEngine but `Integer` is immutable, thus you'd still have the previous value after changing it i JavaScript.

Edit: removing autoboxing to make it more clear:

It's much like this:

```
Integer i = new Integer(17);
Integer j = i;  //should be similar to the assignment in Javascript
j++; //the change to j is not reflected in i

System.out.println(i); //prints 17 not 18
```

Comment: @Jesper, you're right. I should not throw autoboxing in here :) I forgot that autoboxing will also add the assignment to the new Integer object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening in your code:

```
Integer i = new Integer(17);
```

This line creates two things:

- A local variable of type `Integer` with the name `i`.
- A new `Integer` object with the value `17`.

The local variable is initialized with a reference to the newly created `Integer` object (i.e. it points to the `Integer` object now).

The `Integer` object *can't* be modified, since it's immutable.
The local variable *could* be modified by assigning a new reference to it.

```
engine.put( "i", i );
```

This line passes the *value* of `i` (which is the reference to the `Integer` object) to the method `put()`. This means that `put` **only** knows of the `Integer` object and **not** of the *variable* `i`. And since the `Integer` object itself can't be modified, there is **no way** for the method (or any other method) to influence what is stored in the local variable `i`.

```
engine.eval( "i++;" );  // Now execute JavaScript
```

This method effectively manipulates the JavaScript variable `i` created by the line before. That variable was *initialized* with the value of the local Java variable `i`, but **it is not the same as that local variable**.

```
assertEquals( 18, i.intValue() );
```

Here you check the value of the local Java variable `i`, which is unchanged. The **only** way you could make that assert correct is by assigning something else to `i` (e.g. `i = new Integer(18)`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas and Joachim Sauer for pointing out that the problem was due to the immutability of `java.lang.Integer`.

The integer is mapped to a genuine JavaScript variable by `engine.put()` and can be treated like a number. If you need the result, call `engine.get()` to pass it back into Java. This is different to the `List<String>` example on http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/ where a Java object is passed to the script, and *its own methods (as defined in Java)* are applied to it from within the script by callback to Java, using reflection.

It is an interesting detail that the `Integer` will be retrieved as `Double` from JavaScript, indicating that there really was a forward and backward mapping to a JavaScript data object.

Here is the passing test (leaving out the instantiation of `engine` which is still the same as in my question - I have extracted it in the meantime).

```
  @Test 
  public void bindToInteger() throws ScriptException {

    Integer i = 17;

    engine.put( "i", i );        
    engine.eval( "i++" );  // Execute JavaScript

  // i is mapped back to java.lang.Double by get()
    double f = (Double) engine.get("i");  
    assertEquals( 18,  (int) f );        

    }
```